# Unable to start MongoDB with --replSet

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to install Rocket.chat which requires MongoDB, the instruction for configuring MongoDB is here: https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/index.html#install.

I have MongoDB 2.4.10, I appended `replSet=001-rs` to the end of `/etc/mongod.conf` and restarted MongoDB with `systemctl restart mongodb`. However, when I run `rs.initiate()` I get error `server is not running with --replSet`

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10
connecting to: test
> rs.initiate()
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "server is not running with --replSet" }
>
```

Rocket.chat requires MongoDB to run with replSet, I should get a result with `"ok": 1`, similar to this:

```
{
  "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
  "me" : "localhost:27017",
  "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
  "ok" : 1
}
```

How can I start MongoDB 2.4.10 with `--replSet`? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the default port of "mongod" and "mongos"?

Comment: what is O.S environment?

Comment: Are you certain that `/etc/mongod.conf` is the config file being used? Can you add the output of `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` (which should show both the config path and the replSet option)?

Comment: Also note that MongoDB 2.4.10 is a very old version (originally released in April, 2014) and the 2.4 series reached end of life in March, 2016. I would strongly recommend installing a currently supported version of MongoDB (such as latest 3.6.x release) as there have been significant improvements in security, stability, and performance.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan This is Debian Jessie, MongoDB setup is the same for Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: @Stennie `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` shows that `/etc/mongodb.conf` is used. I only try Rocket on a test server now to see if it suits my needs, sure I will need to use new MongoDB for production.

Answer (score 1):

After checking my `/etc/mongod.conf` I noticed that it was the configuration for MongoDB 2.6 and newer, that was why `replSet=001-rs` did nothing. Reinstalling didn't help so I decided to install MongoDB 3.6 from MongoDB's repository, followed the instruction of Rocket.chat and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> I appended replSet=001-rs to the end of /etc/mongod.conf and restarted
>   MongoDB with systemctl restart mongodb. However, when I run
>   rs.initiate() I get error server is not running with --replSet.

As per `rocket.chat BOL` documentation [Here](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/index.html#install)

To restart Mongo :

```
service mongod restart
```

As you have said that after appended **`replSet=001-rs`** to the end of `/etc/mongod.conf` and restarted `MongoDB` with **`systemctl restart mongodb`**.

As per `BOL` documented [Here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/systemctl.1.html) and [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)  `systemctl` may be used to introspect and control the state of the
       **`systemd`** system and **`service manager`**.

To start a **`systemd`** service, executing instructions in the service's unit file, use the start command. If you are running as a **`non-root`** user, you will have to use **`sudo`** since this will affect the state of the operating system:

For example

```
 sudo systemctl start application.service
```

In case of MongoDB, to enable mongodb on startup

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

As **`systemd`** knows to look for **`*.service`** files for service management commands, so the command could just as easily be typed like this:

For Example

```
sudo systemctl start application
```

**to start mongodb**

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

There is troubleshooting trics after making any configuration changes in **`mongod.conf`** file.

1) First killed all mongod with sudo `sudo killall mongod`

2) Now to start mongodb `sudo systemctl start mongodb`

Hope this will help out to you.

For further your ref [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014186/running-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557352/errmsg-server-is-not-running-with-replset)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. `systemctl` and `service` do the same thing in this case. Kill all MongoDB processes then start it doesn't make any differences.